# function to extend a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I create a function that can take any list and extend it. Here is what I am talkig about:

```
  def list(l, p):

      return l.extend(p)
```

I also want to have  p to be of any nature.

Comment: *of any nature*?

Comment: Why not just use `extend`?

Comment: First of all it is very bad that you're redefined builtin `list` ctor. Second, please clarify what do you mean by saying "any nature". Note that there are _iterable_ and _non-iterable_ values in Python, explain which outcome you expect for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't override the keywords, here I post an answer based on my understanding of your question, which is not very clear.

```
def my_list(l, *args):
    from itertools import chain
    sub_lists = filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), args)
    elements = filter(lambda x: not isinstance(x, list), args)
    l.extend(list(chain.from_iterable(sub_lists)))
    l.extend(list(elements))
    return l


l1 = [1, 2]
l2 = [3, 4]
l3 = [5, 6]
e = 7

new_list = my_list(l1, l2, l3, e, 8)

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(new_list)
```

Comment: That'b s exactly what I was looking for .